# How to solve/optimize 9 nonlinear equations using cubic equation solver in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab, math, nonlinear-optimization, nonlinear-functions

I'm having some trouble solving a complex nonlinear system below. logmn as in logmean.

Excel solver is capable of solving the system easily. I'm changing Ff, m, n variables to optimize results (Ff*Xfc-Fp*x-Fr*m)^2*1000 close to 0) from cubic equation solver involves cos(θ/3). However, MATLAB doesn't have such an optimization tool.

```
syms x y z Fr Fp Ff m n k Pr Pp Pf G1 G2 G3 Xfc Xfh Xfn s r L miu

eq1=x+y+z-1==0;
eq2=m+n+k-1==0;
eq3=Fr+Fp-Ff==0;
eq4=m*Fr+Fp*x-Ff*Xfc==0;
eq5=n*Fr+Fp*y-Ff*Xfh==0;
eq6=y*G1*[logmn(Pf,Pr)*logmn(Xfc,m)-x*Pp]-x*G2*[logmn(Pf,Pr)*logmn(Xfh,n)-y*Pp]==0;
eq7=z*G1*[logmn(Pf,Pr)*logmn(Xfc,m)-x*Pp]-x*G3*[logmn(Pf,Pr)*logmn(Xfn,k)-z*Pp]==0;
eq8=Pr-Pf+(8*logmn(Ff,Fr)*miu*L)/(3.14*r^4)==0;
eq9=2*3.14*r*L*s*[G1*[logmn(Pf,Pr)*logmn(Xfc,m)-x*Pp]+G2*[logmn(Pf,Pr)*logmn(Xfh,n)-y*Pp]+G3* 
[logmn(Pf,Pr)*logmn(Xfn,k)-z*Pp]]-Fp==0;
```

I've tried using fsolve and regular solve. But either it gives me imaginary results or an empty array.

Thanks for any input!

Comment: Are you solving symbolically in excel, or minimising the residual `(Ff*Xfc-Fp*x-Fr*m)^2*1000` numerically? Are the other variables known constants? Which 9 variables are you trying to find? What is your `logmn` function? (I don't have it in my Matlab, is it in a toolbox or your own code?) 2 minor comments: Square brackets in Matlab are to denote arrays, use parentheses for grouping, and by 3.14 do you mean pi, or really 3.14?

Comment: Hi David, sorry for the late response. To answer all the questions: yes I'm trying to minimize the residual numerically? The known variables are Ff, Pf, Pp, Xfc, Xfh, Xfn, G1, G2, G3, s, r, L, miu. So left x y z Ff m n k Pr Fr Fp 9 unknowns to solve. logmn is logmean function a-b)/(log(a)-log(b), which made it difficult for matlab to solve. The above is my code function code. Pi is 3.14, and yes I did realize the problem with brackets. Thanks for pointing that out.

Fr, n, m are changing variables in excel solver to minimize (FfXfc-Fpx-Fr*m)^2*1000.

Comment: Try using `fminsearchcon` from the file exchange: https://au.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/8277-fminsearchbnd-fminsearchcon.

Comment: Thanks so much! I'll give it a try